# Google Maps Markers multiple users

Tags: maps

I have an application. The user can do a search (5 mi., 10, etc) and it'll show users who are using that app on the google map. I need help with deciding how to go about making the markers, links to users.

Answer (score 0):

Making the marker is generally trivial.  Google has a number of complete [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) you can study, like [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

Basically you set up your map:

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Then set up your coordinate(s):

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
```

Then create and add your marker(s):

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

Simple.  If you want to handle clicks on the marker (to do things like link to a user-details page), you do something like:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //<code to go to user's profile page>
  });
```

The more challenging problem in your case will be figuring out which coordinates to use for the markers.  That's a much more complicated answer.  The short version is, it depends.